# Add Total of an Multidimensional Array

Tags: awk, gawk

### Question

I have the following array:

`scansum[key,key2]++`

`key` = multiple 6 digit numbers eg. 123456, 234567, 345678 etc.

`key2` = a hour eg. 00, 01, 02 etc.

### Sample Code

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
BEGIN {
        printf ("---------------------------------------\n-----CTS_DR Read Report By Scanner-----\n---------------------------------------\n")
        }
                {
                key = substr ($16,3,6) #Scanner
                key2 = substr ($2,1,3) #Hour
                scanner[key]++
                if ($21 ~ /SR1/) scansum[key,key2]++
                }
END {
                for (scan in scanner) {
                        printf ("\nScanner: MS%6s\tTotal Reads:%8s\n",scan,scanner[scan])
                        for (i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                                        if (i < 10)
                                        h = "0" i
                                        else
                                        h = i
                                print "Hour: "h " Count Test: "scansum[scan,h]
                                }
                        }
}'
```

I know that for a normal array you can just do:

```
for (alias in arrayname) {
print arrayname[alias]
}
```

and this will do a count of the array split by the key but for a multidimensional array  the following doesn't seem to work:

```
for (alias in arrayname) {
  print alias
  for (i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
      if (i <10)
      h = "0" i
      else
      h = i
  print h"\t"arraynamecount[alias,h]
  }
}
```

**Note**

I know that this is missing the setting of the array

I know I am missing something but I can't for the life of me see what it is. Any hints/ help for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you use awk 4.0 true 2D arrays?

Comment: For multidimensional arrays, your `alias` variable contains string values matching the format `key[SUBSEP]key2` where `[SUBSEP]` stands for the character `\034`. Read this section about [awk multidimensional arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiscanning)

Comment: @pakistanprogrammerclub unfortunately I can't use `awk 4.0` true 2D arrays because the system is running a old version of `awk` and the business have decided not to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiscanning), you can use the `split()` function to get an array for every index of an `awk` multidimensional array because every index of the form

```
key1,key2,···,keyN
```

is stored as a string

```
key1[SUBSEP]key2[SUBSEP]···[SUBSEP]keyN
```

where `[SUBSEP]` stands for the ASCII character hold in the **`SUBSEP`** variable, which by default is `\034`. In fact you can access any multidimensional array element alternatively using that string:

```
x=myarray[key1 SUBSEP key2]
```

Basically the `END` block should look similar to this

```
END {
      for (scan in scansum) {
        split(scan,ind,SUBSEP)
        print "Scanner: " ind[1] "\tHour: " ind[2] "\tCount Test: " scansum[ind[1],ind[2]]
      }
}
```

Comment: Just for information purposes, I have found that you can do a Total of a multidimensional array in the same way as a single key array, `arrayname[key]`, but you have to make sure the 2 strings you are using to compare the strings which in my case was the hour,`00,01,02... etc` is the same. I have the original `substr` pulling an additional character, a `:`, which was causing the arrays to miss match on the hardcoded hour.